# Import CSV file with extension yii2-csv-importer

Tags: yii2, import-csv

I'm not sure how to use the extension **"yii2-csv-importer"**.
I need to import a CSV file that is in the **app/web/uploads/mod-key.csv** directory

My table/model (BASE) and csv file have the following structure:

```
'id'
'date'
'Pan
'key'
'goal'
'accomplished'
'Weight'
'points'
'update'
```

How would my ACTION look?

**UPDATE**

```
use ruskid\csvimporter\CSVImporter;
use ruskid\csvimporter\CSVReader;
use ruskid\csvimporter\ImportInterface;
use ruskid\csvimporter\MultipleImportStrategy;
use ruskid\csvimporter\BaseImportStrategy;


$importer = new CSVImporter();

$importer->setData(new CSVReader([
'filename' => Yii::$app->request->baseUrl."/uploads/mod-key.csv",
'tableName' => Base::tableName(),
'fgetcsvOptions' => [
'delimiter' => ';'
]
]));

$numberRowsAffected = $importer->import(new MultipleImportStrategy([
'tableName' => ModelName::tableName(), // change your model names accordingly
'configs' => [
[
    'attribute' => 'id',
    'value' => function($line) {
        return $line[0];
    }
],
[
    'attribute' => 'date',
    'value' => function($line) {
        return $line[1];
    }
]
// put your remaining columns here
],
]));
```

Comment: Can someone give some help?

Comment: Fix (see the UPDATE)

Comment: I think that `filename` attribute should be filesystem path, so `Yii::$app->request->baseUrl` does not return filesystem path, it returns [tag:url]

Comment: i change it to: Yii::getAlias('@webroot')."/uploads/mod-key.csv",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use ruskid\csvimporter\CSVImporter;
use ruskid\csvimporter\CSVReader;
use ruskid\csvimporter\ImportInterface;
use ruskid\csvimporter\MultipleImportStrategy;
use ruskid\csvimporter\BaseImportStrategy;


$importer = new CSVImporter();

$importer->setData(new CSVReader([
'filename' => Yii::$app->request->baseUrl."/uploads/mod-key.csv",
'tableName' => Base::tableName(),
'fgetcsvOptions' => [
'delimiter' => ';'
]
]));

$numberRowsAffected = $importer->import(new MultipleImportStrategy([
'tableName' => ModelName::tableName(), // change your model names accordingly
'configs' => [
[
    'attribute' => 'id',
    'value' => function($line) {
        return $line[0];
    }
],
[
    'attribute' => 'date',
    'value' => function($line) {
        return $line[1];
    }
]
// put your remaining columns here
],
]));
```